# Hammer.js swipe does not working on rotated iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, hammer.js

I made an iframe on the page and rotated it by transform.

```
    body.rotate iframe {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: top right;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        right: 0;
        height:100vw;
        min-width:100vh;
    }
```

and tried to add swipe event on the page in an iframe.

```
    var el = document.getElementById('swipe');
    Hammer(el).on('swipeleft', next);
    Hammer(el).on('swiperight', prev);
    Hammer(el).on('doubletap', preview);
```

When I doubletap on div#swipe in the rotated iframe, preview() is triggered. but swipeleft and swiperight doesn't work.

Comment: If you doubletap on where the `div#swipe` would be without the rotation, does it work then?

Comment: doubletap always works but swipeleft and swiperight doesn't work when iframe is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this guide.

```
var el = document.getElementById('swipe');
var mc = new Hammer(el);
mc.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
Hammer(el).on('swipeleft', next);
Hammer(el).on('swiperight', prev);
Hammer(el).on('doubletap', preview);
```